# How to backup entire xen dom0 (on debian)

Tags: debian, backup, xen

How do you go about creating a bootable backup ISO of my computer (dom0)?

I have tried `remastersys` and this backs up everything but Xen does not work properly.  LiveCDs also do not work.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I could?  Would a simple `cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdb` work ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `fsarchiver` to backup a volume. Available in most linux repository.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to make bootable backup ISO, but maybe this will help you a little bit more.

As you wrote

```
cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdb
```

will not work. Instead of command cat use command dd

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=512
```

This dd command will create exact copy of your disk /dev/sda to /dev/sdb. You can also copy it to a file, you do not need to use another partition/disk for it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a way to do a "cat" like thing. I want to use my swiss army knife to send it over a network chunk by chunk